# Mac App Store sandboxing and handling security-scoped bookmarks prior to 10.7.3

Tags: macos, cocoa, app-store, sandbox, bookmarks

I need my sandboxed app to reopen an opened file after the app is restarted.  Apple provides security-scoped bookmarks with the `NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope` and `NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithSecurityScope` options in the NSURL bookmark creation and resolving methods.  However, these flags/options are only good for 10.7.3 or later and cause an app prior to 10.7.3 to fail.

How do I handle retention/reopening of the file bookmark for 10.6 to 10.7.3 in a sandboxed app?

--

FOLLOW-UP:  Please see my answer below.  The issue was not caused by using `NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope` but by using the security-scoped bookmark start and stop methods.

Comment: My guess is that you probably can't. This was a shortcoming in their sandboxing approach, and the extra mechanism was added because of that. And Apple is not one to backport things...

Comment: Are you sure that's the cause of the failure? I have an app (in MAS) that uses `[NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:bookmark options:NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithSecurityScope relativeToURL:nil bookmarkDataIsStale:NO error:nil];` that works just fine on 10.6.8 machines.

Comment: @Patrick - does it work fine on 10.7 - 10.7.2? (The sandbox is non-operational on 10.6.8 and resolution of the URL may just ignored any security info added by 10.7.3+ - just guessing)

Comment: Hm, I should have checked Console.app more thoroughly.  I get these error messages when testing on 10.7.1: `-[NSURL startAccessingSecurityScopedResource]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10420e180`  Does this mean I need to wrap the start/stop methods with an OS X 10.7.3 or greater version check?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out using `NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope` does not cause an issue with 10.7 - 10.7.2.  What causes the failure is calling `-[NSURL startAccessingSecurityScopedResource]:` which is not supported prior to 10.7.3.  Therefore, you need to wrap calls to this method (and the corresponding stop method) with an OS check or a respondsToSelector check.  I tested that the bookmark still works in 10.7.1 as long as you make sure not to call start/stop.

Here are some code snippet for using `respondsToSelector` that will help any others that run in to this problem:

Use this to start usage:

```
if([bookmarkFileURL respondsToSelector:@selector(startAccessingSecurityScopedResource)]) { // only supported by 10.7.3 or later
    [bookmarkFileURL startAccessingSecurityScopedResource]; // start using bookmarked resource
}
```

And this to stop usage:

```
if([bookmarkFileURL respondsToSelector:@selector(stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource)]) { // only supported by 10.7.3 or later
    [bookmarkFileURL stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource]; // stop using bookmarked resource
}
```

Comment: Why not just using respondsToSelector instead of checking the OS version?

Comment: @Ben-Uri You're right, `respondsToSelector` is a better implementation than checking the OS version.  I updated the answer.